# Send emails from protractor in typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

I do not know is it possible to send emails with node mailer, or any other plug in from Protractor(in typescript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do:

First you need to install nodemailer

```
npm install nodemailer
```

Import `nodemailer` in your protractor config file

by this way you can able to do:

**config-file**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');    
onComplete: function () {
        return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
          var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
              user: 'abc@gmail.com',
              pass: '12346788'
            }
          });
          var mailOptions = {
            from: 'abc@gmail.com',
            to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Test_Report',
            text: 'Test_Report of app',
            attachments: [{
              'path': 'Test_Report/htmlReport.html',
            }]
          };
          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
              reject(err);
              return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Mail sent: ' + info.response);
            fulfill(info);
          });
        });
    }
```

*Additional:* 
If you sending test report that fails or passed then you need to install below packages

package --> `cucumber-html-reporter`

```
npm install cucumber-html-reporter --save-dev
```

and configure it into protractor config file.

It's working fine for me.Hope it helps to you also.

Comment: I am not working with jasmine. I am working with cucumber and TYPESCRIPT. Are you sure that this solution can be apply to the protractor->Cucumber->Typescript? I have tried and it is NOT working. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: whether it's cucumber or jasmine, configuration remain same. changes done accordingly for cucumber.

Comment: you need to install nodemailer too: please check this https://chercher.tech/protractor/send-email-nodemailer-protractor

Comment: I read already the link that you send in comment and I found this "Unfortunately, I was not able to send the mail using test block or with typescript, so please do follow below steps to send the email with nodeMailer. Below are the steps to configure nodemailer", I am currently going on to vocation, but I will check this. On first ball, I have compile errors on this line - "onComplete:", and on  "reject(err);"

Comment: okay.Hope it runs because I'm sending test report by same way